# Chrome Extension Newbie Question - check web page for entries, click hyperlink and refresh

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am just starting out writing my first Chrome plugin so hopefully I ask this question using the right vocabulary.  Also looked for other questions that might be the same as this one and didn't find any that covered what I was looking for.

I've read the documentation on creating a Chrome Extension and have done the "Hello World" extension and see it write its output to the background console log.  However, I'm not sure exactly how I would structure the extension I want to build between background and content.  Any help/pointers (and examples) would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I'd like the extension to accomplish:

- Have it appear in the toolbar where other extensions appear
- Have it be able to be enabled/disabled
- When enabled:

  - Read data from the current page
  - If it finds certain entries "click" on the hyperlink to select them
  - Sleep for 5 seconds
  - Repeat the process

Or if there is another extension that does something similar already if you can point me to it maybe I can base my code off the same structure

Comment: So far there's no need for the background script. You can provide a UI to toggle the functionality in browser_action popup. It will inject a content script when the "go" button is clicked, the content script will access the web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your response.  Is there an example you could point me to that does that (that I'd obviously have to tailor to my needs)?  Sorry - first time attempting this

Comment: There's nothing mind-boggling in the workflow. Try the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).